# ¿Como guardar el valor de un dropdownlist aplicacion web en una variable?

Tags: javascript, c#

Tengo una aplicación Web con C#, la cual genera una página con varios `dropdownlist`.

Los `dropdownlist` se rellenan a partir de un procedimiento almacenado *(SP)*, lo que requiero es que al seleccionar un valor del dropdownlist *(cualquiera)* me lo almacene en una variable para poder utilizarla como filtro de un nuevo SP que estoy construyendo.

Adjunto el código con el cual estoy tratando de almacenar el valor de este *dropdownlist*; estoy utilizando *JavaScript* para guardarlo, pero no me muestra nada.

Este es el código:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Home.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PanelGeneral.aspx.cs" Inherits="SistemaDashBoardFEMSA.PanelGeneral" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        #formulario_grafica {
            width: 1068px;
            height: 105px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <section class="content-header">
        <h3 style="text-align:center">REPORTES MENSUALES FEMSA</h3>
    </section>

    <section class="container">
        <div class ="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"> <!--DROPDOWNLIST-->
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dpl_semanas" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpl_fechas_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class ="col-sm-4">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dpl_meses" runat="server" style ="width: auto"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class ="col-sm-4">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="Zonas" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>            
        </div>

        <div class="row"> <!--ESTE ES EL BOTON QUE GENERA EL EVENTO-->
            <asp:Button ID="genera_reporte" runat="server" Text="Generar" OnClientClick="mostrar()"/>                


                <script type ="text/javascript">
                    function mostrar() {
                        variable = dpl_meses.items(dpl_meses.SelectedIndex).Text;
                        alert("Hola");
                    }

                </script>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_prueba" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>


    &nbsp;</div>
    </section>

    <section class ="container">
        <iframe src="Graficas.aspx" style="width: 1019px; height: 480px;" :></iframe>

    </section>

</asp:Content>
```

SOLUCION:

Este es el método que controla el relleno de los dropdrownlist, el dropdrownlist que lleva por nombre "lbl_prueba" se rellena con dpl_meses.selectedItem.text. Pero si no agregan al inicio la instrucción (!Page.IsPostback), no se los rellenara. Debido a ser una aplicación WEB, a cada carga de página, se pierden los datos de los dropdrownlist, por lo tanto si no es(!Page.IsPostBack) no vuelva a cargar la página y evite que se reseteen.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace SistemaDashBoardFEMSA
{
    public partial class PanelGeneral : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {


            clsConexioncs conexion_server = new clsConexioncs();

            conexion_server.Conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultDW"].ToString();


            //-----------------combos
            conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("prm_spFEMSA_SemanasIndicadoresTelemetria");

            conexion_server.LlenaComboConConsulta(dpl_semanas, "Semana", "RangoFechas");


            conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("sp_meses_femsa");
            conexion_server.LlenaComboConConsulta(dpl_meses, "Mes", null);

            conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("prm_spFEMSA_SemanasIndicadoresTelemetria");
            conexion_server.LlenaComboConConsulta(Zonas, "FechaFin", "RangoFechas");

            //---------------------------    

        }
    }

    protected void dpl_fechas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //lbl_prueba.Text = dpl_fechas.SelectedValue;
    }




    protected void genera_reporte_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void dpl_meses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lbl_prueba.Text = dpl_meses.SelectedItem.Text; //esta label, se llana a partir de la selección del item del drop

    }


}
```

}

Comment: $("#dpl_meses").val()  //con jquery document.getElementById('dpl_meses').value //con javascript

Comment: Que crees, de esa manera ya lo había intentado, pero, no me muestra nada. ¿Alguna otra forma?

Comment: entra a la función mostrar()? te marca algún error? para ver el error en chrome presionas F12

Comment: Y por qué no usas código c# para almacenar el valor en una variable?

Comment: @Ric_hc la razón del porqué al colocar el valor del dropdownlist en un Label y no aparece puede ser porque se genera postback que hace que la página se recarge. por favor, mira los comentarios que la comunidad de SOes ha dejado y actualiza tu pregunta para ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, ya pude resolver el problema. Efectivamente utilice mejor código C#, les agrego la solución como quedo. El por que queria hacerlo con JavaScript, fue por que deseaba hacerlo de manera dinámica y actualizarlo con AJAX. Pero, ya pude resolverlo, Lo voy a agregar sobre el mismo bloque de código de mi pregunta, para compartirles la respuesta a ver que les parece, si alguien le sirve adelante.

Comment: @Ric_hc que buen que hayas encontrado una solución, te recomiendo [responder a tu propia pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es el método que controla el relleno de los `dropdrownlist`, el dropdrownlist que lleva por nombre `lbl_prueba` se rellena con `dpl_meses.selectedItem.text`. Pero si no agregan al inicio la instrucción `(!Page.IsPostback)`, no se los rellenara. Debido a ser una aplicación WEB, a cada carga de página, se pierden los datos de los dropdrownlist, por lo tanto si no es `(!Page.IsPostBack)` no vuelva a cargar la página y evite que se reseteen.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {


        clsConexioncs conexion_server = new clsConexioncs();

        conexion_server.Conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultDW"].ToString();


        //-----------------combos
        conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("prm_spFEMSA_SemanasIndicadoresTelemetria");

        conexion_server.LlenaComboConConsulta(dpl_semanas, "Semana", "RangoFechas");


        conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("sp_meses_femsa");
        conexion_server.LlenaComboConConsulta(dpl_meses, "Mes", null);

        conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("prm_spFEMSA_SemanasIndicadoresTelemetria");
        conexion_server.LlenaComboConConsulta(Zonas, "FechaFin", "RangoFechas");

        //---------------------------    

    }
}

protected void dpl_fechas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //lbl_prueba.Text = dpl_fechas.SelectedValue;
}




protected void genera_reporte_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void dpl_meses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    lbl_prueba.Text = dpl_meses.SelectedItem.Text; //esta label, se llana a partir de la selección del item del drop

}


}
```

Comment: Hola Ric_hc qué bueno que encontraste la respuesta a tu pregunta, recuerda marcar tu pregunta como válida en 48 horas, así mismo, sugiero que edites tu pregunta quitando la parte de la *solución* ya que se puede leer como una pregunta muy extensa y tu respuesta indicaría lo que deseas transmitir :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, espero les sirva a alguien. Saludos.